# Can't extend FieldsChunk class (from INET) inside .msg file

Tags: omnet++, inet

I need to make a MANET routing protocol, so I'm looking at GPSR and DSDV source code in INET to get an insight of how to do it.

I checked the files `DsdvHello.msg` and `Gpsr.msg` where the classes that represent packets of these protocols are defined. Those classes extend `FieldsChunk` class. I assumed that I had to define the packets of my protocol the same way, so I made the file `Protocolo.msg` in my project like the following.

```
cplusplus {{
#include "inet/common/packet/chunk/FieldsChunk.h"
#include "inet/networklayer/contract/ipv6/Ipv6Address.h"
}}

class FieldsChunk;
class Ipv6Address;

class Hola extends FieldsChunk {

    Ipv6Address ip;
    string ubicacion;
}

class Adios extends FieldsChunk {

    Ipv6Address ip;
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing right, but I'm doing it as I see in `DsdvHello.msg` and `Gpsr.msg` and the Message Definitions chapter in the OMNeT++ Simulation Manual.

I selected INET in Project>Properties>Project References, but when I build my project, I get the message `fatal error: inet/common/packet/chunk/FieldsChunk.h: No such file or directory` when it tries to compile my `.msg` file.

I also have a NED file that uses IManetRouting (also from INET) without problems, but for some reason it doesn't find `FieldsChunk.h` and `IPv6Address.h` inside the `.msg` file.

Can anyone tell me if I need to do anything else so that I can use those classes in my `.msg` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change `Protocolo.msg` into:

   ```
   import inet.common.INETDefs;
   import inet.common.packet.chunk.Chunk;
   import inet.networklayer.contract.ipv6.Ipv6Address;

   namespace inet;

   class Hola extends FieldsChunk {
     Ipv6Address ip;
     string ubicacion;
   }

   class Adios extends FieldsChunk {
     Ipv6Address ip;
   }
   ```
2. Then go to `Properties` of your project, select `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | src folder | `Options...` and:

   - in `Compile` tab check "Add include paths exported from referenced projects"
   - in `Custom` tab add the following line:

     ```
     MSGC:=$(MSGC) --msg6
     ```

Comment: Yes. INET 4 is already using the OMNeT++6 compatible message compiler, however OMNeT++5 still defaults to the old message file format, so you have to specifically enable it for your project as suggested above. On OMNeT++6 the last step will not be required as it defaults to the new message file format.